# flask_sqlalchemy create_all without having to import models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to understand how to set up a standalone script that calls `create_all` without having to import all my models into it. Below are the relevant files:

**`db.py`**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**`test_model.py`**

```
from db import db

class TestTable(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

and **`create_all.py`**

```
from db import db

db.create_all()
```

However, `create_all` will not do anything, as it does not detect any tables registered to it, unless they are imported. Is there a way when declaring models to have them added to the "registry" to bypass the explicit import?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. You will have to import those models before the call to `create_all()`, one way or the other. The declarative classes build the `Table` instances and add them to the `MetaData` when the class itself is constructed. If the `MetaData` contains no tables, `create_all` will do nothing.

Put another way, "declaring models" does nothing unless those declarations are evaluated, so the module must be executed. Importing from it does just that.