# Error with relationships of SQLAlchemy models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have 2 models in separate files

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "books"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str]
    description: Mapped[str]
    author_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("authors.id"))
    janres: Mapped[list[str]] = mapped_column(JSON)
    image_id: Mapped[int]
    publish_date: Mapped[date] = mapped_column(Date)

    author: Mapped["Author"] = relationship(back_populates="books")
```

```
class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "authors"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    surname: Mapped[str]
    birth_date: Mapped[date] = mapped_column(Date)
    death_date: Mapped[Optional[date]] = mapped_column(Date)

    books: Mapped[list["Book"]] = relationship(back_populates="author")
```

And when I create relationship I have an SQLAlchemy error
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Author(authors)], expression 'Books' failed to locate a name ('Books'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.author.models.Author'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

What I did wrong?

When I delete fields with relationships error disappear too

Comment: An immediate solution would be to put both models in the same file

Comment: Some of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51155963/5320906) might be useful